# Why is a type discriminator needed in the DB when the .NET runtime can determine the type needed?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Referring to this:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/serialization/polymorphic-objects/#use-discriminators

If my classes are properly annotated (or mapped), why does the type discriminator need to be written out to the database (the "_t" value)? Doesn't the runtime have enough information to do serdes correctly? Do the drivers for other document DBs do this?

Having "_t" in the database seems unnecessary in terms of data topology if it's strictly used for a specific application's runtime. It's also unnecessary in terms of storage/query costs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the classes you have, any mapping/annotations you have, example data in your MongoDB and the expected deserialized classes from these example data. Also explain how MongoDB should identify which target class should be used for deserialization.

Comment: @Progman I am not referring to anything specific that I'm using. I'm simply asking a question about what the linked documentation says. So I would simply refer to the example(s) the documentation is using.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the need for the discriminator field? As stated in the documentation, it is for specifying the type of the target class for deserialization.

Comment: @Progman The runtime knows the type I'm trying to access either because it's a typed class I'm querying or because I've annotated it. Having the discriminator value written to the database seems irrelevant and unnecessary. No other document DB does this that I'm aware of. Even in the examples in the documentation, if I'm querying the collection for `Cat`, even if it's a derived typed from `Animal`, it knows I am asking for a collection of `Cat`, e.g. `animalDatabase.GetCollection<Cat>("animal")`. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The discriminator field is needed in case there are multiple different types stored in the MongoDB. The .NET/C# driver alone cannot know the resulting type when deserializing, specially with inheritance involved. When you want all `Animal` instances from the database and send a request like that, then the return values shouldn't be "just" `Animal` instances. Instead the instances should be from classes like `Dog`, `Lion` or `Tiger` (which ultimately extends from `Animal`). Without the discriminator, you don't know if the animal stored was/is a dog, lion or tiger. Also, when you want to filter rows and select only `Lion` instances, then you need the discriminator field as well, since you need to know, which rows are lions and which rows are not.

You could argue that the combination of value fields from the model classes alone can be used to uniquely identify a specific type. However, there can be cases (depending on the model classes of course), that the value fields alone are not enough to identify the class type. As an example, the value `{"Name": "Foobar"}` could be an `Employee`, `Product` or `Group`.